# displaying content in div depending on link hovered

Tags: jquery, css

When hovering over one of the links, the goal is to display the div specific to the link inside the browsebox.

How can this be done?

```
<div> 
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">ARTISTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GENRES</a></li>
<li><a href="#">COLLECTIONS</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="browsebox">
<div class="artist"></div>
<div class="genre"></div>
<div class="collection"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Each of the child divs for browsebox are hidden:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#secondary-links li").mouseover(function(){
        $("#browsebox").slideDown(500, function(){
            $(this).addClass("shown");
            $(this).mouseleave( function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(200);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the divs that related to the links will have have links in it so the browsebox div will need to stay in hover state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/3WjF7/4/

HTML:

```
<div> 
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a rel="artist" href="#">ARTISTS</a><div class="artist">Artist info here </div></li>
        <li><a rel="genre" href="#">GENRES</a><div class="genre">Genre info here</div></li>
        <li><a rel="collection" href="#">COLLECTIONS</a><div class="collection">Collection info here</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
li>a{
    display:block;
    width:100px;
}
li>div {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.menu li').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children('div').slideDown();
    });

    $('.menu li').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('div').slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is perfect but I forgot to mention that the content in the browse box div will have links, is it possible to keep the div in hover state?

Comment: Replace mouseenter with mousover and replace mouseleave with mousout.

Comment: Hey i just tried to change the jsfiddle link and didn't seem to work unless i did something wrong

Comment: Ah sorry I misread your request. You'll want to also put the sliding divs INSIDE the event with the mouseover listener

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

First you need someway to link up those hrefs to corresponding `div`s. Something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-div="artist">ARTISTS</a>
<a href="#" data-div="genre">GENRES</a>
<a href="#"  data-div="collection">COLLECTIONS</a>
```

Then this:

```
$("ul.menu a").mousein(function() {
   $($(this).data("div")).show();
}).mouseout(function() {
   $($(this).data("div")).hide();
});
```